# Android: does short take really 2 bytes?

Tags: android, short

I am trying to make decision how to design my app.

I have about 300 instances of class just like this:

```
public class ParamValue {

   protected String sValue = null;
   protected short  shValue = 0;
   protected short  mode = PARAM_VALUE_MODE_UNKNOWN;

   /*
    * ...
    */
}
```

I have an array of these instances. I can't find out does these shorts really take 2 bytes or they take anyway 4 bytes?

And i need to pass the list of these objects via AIDL as a `List<Parcelable>`. Parcel can't `readShort()` and `writeShort()`, it can only work with `int`. So, to use short here too i have to manually pack two my shorts into one int, parcel it, and then unpack back. Looks too obtrusive.

Could you please tell me how many bytes shorts take, and does it make sense to use short instead of int here?

**UPDATE:**

I updated my question for future readers.

So, I wrote a test app and I figured out that in my case there's absolutely no reason to use `short`, because it takes the same space as `int`. But if I define array of shorts like that:

```
 protected short[] myValues[2];
```

then it takes less space than array of ints:

```
 protected int[] myValues[2];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, in the Java language, a `short` is 2 bytes. Inside the JVM, though, `short` is a *storage type*, not a full-fledged primitive data type like `int`, `float`, or `double`. JVM registers always hold 4 bytes at a time; there are no half-word or byte registers. Whether the JVM ever actually stores a `short` in two bytes inside an object, or whether it is always stored as 4 bytes, is really up to the implementation.

This all holds for a "real" JVM. Does Dalvik do things differently? Dunno.

Comment: so, it seems like there's no reason to use short if i trying to achieve less memory usage?

Comment: I would write a test program that creates a large number of objects and measures the free memory before and after with `Runtime.freeMemory()` and run it on the actual production JVM. Do this for both ways of defining the object, and see if you can detect a difference. There may or may not be a difference, but this will let you see for sure.

Comment: I don't think it's up to the implementation, at least in the case of arrays, if it's going to support JNI.

Comment: Agreed, but arrays are different from ordinary objects, though.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill, i wrote a test program and i found out that in my case `short` takes the same space as `int`. I updated my question (added more detailed explanation). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Virtual Machine Specification, Sec. 2.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#19511), a `short` is always exactly two bytes.

The [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp1253) allows direct access from native code to arrays of primitives stored in the VM. A similar thing can happen in [Android's JNI](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/jni.html). This pretty much guarantees that a Java `short[]` will be an array of 2-byte values in either a JVM-compliant environment or in a Dalvik virtual machine.

Comment: but, in my case there is an array of instances of class containing two shorts, not an array like `short[]`. Well, i really need to test it. And thanks for the links, i'll examine it.