# Memory required for 'short' fields in Dalvik?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

Java virtual machines may use `int`-sized width for `short` fields as well (this depends on their internal implementation). Only the arrays (`short[]`) are exception, where it is always guaranteed that they take less space than an `int[]` internally as well). What about *Dalvik*?

E.g. I have a class which contains 50 fields of type `short`. Sometimes in my application, 10000 of these classes exist. This means that the `short` fields should use 1MB of memory, but *if* Dalvik uses 4 bytes for `short` values internally, then this will be 2MB memory usage.

How much memory should I expect Dalvik to use? (This refers to its internal memory use, and I'm aware of the fact that it might not be reflected by the system memory usage, e.g. because Dalvik already reserved a higher amount of memory from the system.)

Comment: To the user who prepared a (formatting) edit to my post: thanks. Unfortunately, the system didn't let me accept it, it said "edit was already rejected". So as far as I could recall, I tried to apply your edits on my own.

Comment: "Java virtual machines are known for using int-sized width for short fields as well" could you back up this statement with any reference?

Comment: I was a bit inaccurate there, so I edited it. Here are some related stackoverflow topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855754/android-does-short-take-really-2-bytes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904857/which-is-better-to-use-short-or-int

Comment: First link Ted Hopp answer clearly answering your question I guess.

Comment: @Nambari: it does not. It just quotes the Java spec. Indeed, 'short' is guaranteed to *appear* and *act* as 2 bytes to any application code. I'm wondering about the internal implementation of Dalvik, and whether it *may* affect memory usage whether I use 10000 classes with 50 short fields, or I use a short[] in each of them instead.

Comment: @Thomas Calc Your question is answered by one of those questions you linked to. "But if I define array of shorts like that... then it takes less space than array of ints"

Comment: @JesusFreke I don't see how the linked questions answer this one. This question is asking about *implementations* of Dalvik (not Java, as Dalvik doesn't use Java Bytecode), not the Java specification (which doesn't mandate either-or) and/or common JVM implementations which might be less memory-savvy. (Note that Ted Hopp's link refers to `short[]` which has different requirements due to index-access [from JNI].)

Comment: @JesusFreke: yes, in one of those linked topics, the OP made a test as well, which states that he saved memory only in case of `short[]`, and not in case of individual `short` fields. As pst pointed out above, Dalvik may work differently. In several aspects, Dalvik indeed works differently than JVMs (as it's mobile-optimized). In this case, it's reasonable to assume that it treats `short[]` in the same way as JVMs (it would be unacceptable for various reasons if a `short[]` used more memory). My question is about the opposite: how does Dalvik store **individual** `short` fields internally?

Comment: @pst and Thomas Calc: question 8855754 is specifically about Android. You might have noticed that the standard JVM doesn't run on Android. Therefore, it is (probably) safe to assume he ran his test on dalvik :)

Comment: @JesusFreke: you're right, I overlooked that when checking the topic again (so I've just upvoted your comment). But for me, this isn't sufficient (neither in detail nor in generality): "So, I wrote a test app and I figured out that in my case there's absolutely no reason to use short, because it takes the same space as int". What was the test app he mentions? It would be nice to see the exact code (we all know testing can be tricky). A test based on *Hot Licks* answer would be nice (I plan to do it). Moreover, I was also hoping for a more theoretical answer from a dev like Dianne Hackborn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dalvik, double and long fields are 8 bytes, everything else (including short) is 4 bytes.

On the other hand, short arrays take 2 bytes per element (in addition to up-front space for the array+object bookkeeping).

**Arrays**

The [`new-array`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/e206e7c9f1c58c77ca51f6e80483c94f6c779e4e/vm/mterp/c/OP_NEW_ARRAY.cpp) opcode calls [`dvmAllocArrayByClass`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/e206e7c9f1c58c77ca51f6e80483c94f6c779e4e/vm/oo/Array.cpp) (line 71) to allocate space. This then calls `dvmAllocPrimitiveArray` (line 113). In the switch in `dvmAllocPrimitiveArray`, the 'S' case is used for a short array. You can see it calls `allocArray` (line 38) with width=2.

Within `allocArray`, it does the following computation to calculate the size size of the array:

```
size_t elementShift = sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - CLZ(elemWidth);
size_t elementSize = length << elementShift;
size_t headerSize = OFFSETOF_MEMBER(ArrayObject, contents);
size_t totalSize = elementSize + headerSize;
```

For a short, on a 32 bit system, this calculation would be:

```
size_t elementShift = (4 * 8) - 1 - 30; //== 1;
size_t elementSize = length << 1; //i.e. length * 2
size_t headerSize = <some constant value>;
size_t totalSize = length*2 + <some constant value>;
```

Short arrays take 2 bytes per element.

**Fields**

The [`new-instance`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/e206e7c9f1c58c77ca51f6e80483c94f6c779e4e/vm/mterp/c/OP_NEW_INSTANCE.cpp) opcode calls [`dvmAllocObject`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/e206e7c9f1c58c77ca51f6e80483c94f6c779e4e/vm/alloc/Alloc.cpp) (line 181) to allocate space for the new object. The size that is allocated is based on the `objectSize` field of `ClassObject`. `objectSize` is set in [`computeFieldOffsets`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/e206e7c9f1c58c77ca51f6e80483c94f6c779e4e/vm/oo/Class.cpp) (line 3543). If you find every instance of where fieldOffset is incremented in this function, you will notice it is always incremented in steps of 4 bytes.

Short fields take 4 bytes.

Comment: This is exactly the type of analytical answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(Would be a comment, but it's too long for that.)

It's fairly routine for 4-byte fields to be used for "short" local vars, since the JVM is conceptually a machine with 4-byte registers, and with all the other garbage in a stack frame it doesn't make much difference.

For instance fields it's likely to depend on the tradeoff of saving storage vs having to spend cycles on widening and alignment -- widening often costs a minor cycle, and even on architectures that are supposedly "agnostic" with regard to boundary alignment there's usually a penalty for off-boundary access, so "packing" fields without first rearranging them to maintain word/doubleword boundaries can cost performance.

So if the JVM chooses to "pack" the fields rearranging is generally required.  Naive JVMs will avoid rearranging since this makes several aspects of the JVM simpler, but (as one example) on AS/400 we found that aggressively reordering and packing instance fields gained on the order of 30% performance improvement for storage-hungry apps.

I've never looked at the innards of Dalvik.  Standard Sun-derived JVMs have historically (not looked at anything recent) been dependent on the layout/order of things in the .class file, and thus not "naturally" amenable to reordering.  But Dalvik re-constitutes the .class file and so is in a better position to do instance field reordering.

Note that to test the hypothesis that Dalvik packs `short` fields you'd have to create a class with several dozen instance fields back-to-back, and then determine what the resulting object size was.  Also (assuming packing is seen in the first case), create a class with `short` and `int` (or maybe `long`) fields interleaved, to see if Dalvik reorders them to achieve packing.